# CiviRules Multiple rules per trigger - What happens?

Tags: civirules

When using CiviRules, what happens if two rules match a single trigger?  Rule one says "if group X is added, filter matches X location, then send e-mail X."  Rule two says "if group X is added, filter matches Y location, then send e-mail Y."  Do both rules trigger?  Does it dump after triggering the first applicable reached rule, even if the filter doesn't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should do both. I have two rules with the same trigger -  membership changed with different conditions- (a) membership status is one of the ones I consider active and (b) membership status is one that I do not consider active. Both are working. But I'd still do some tests on your precise requirement to see that it does what you want.